# Magento Exception Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magentoce.tax_calculation_rule' doesn't exist

Tags: magento

I have installed magento, from home page I clicked on a product, it is giving error: `347147223`.

There has been an error processing your request

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magentoce.tax_calculation_rule' doesn't exist, query was: (SELECT `main_table`.`tax_calculation_rate_id`, `main_table`.`tax_calculation_rule_id`, `main_table`.`customer_tax_class_id`, `main_table`.`product_tax_class_id`, `rule`.`priority`, `rule`.`position`, `rule`.`calculate_subtotal`, `rate`.`rate` AS `value`, `rate`.`tax_country_id`, `rate`.`tax_region_id`, `rate`.`tax_postcode`, `rate`.`tax_calculation_rate_id`, `rate`.`code`, IF(title_table.value IS NULL, rate.code, title_table.value) AS `title` FROM `tax_calculation` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `tax_calculation_rule` AS `rule` ON `rule`.`tax_calculation_rule_id` = main_table.tax_calculation_rule_id
 INNER JOIN `tax_calculation_rate` AS `rate` ON rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = main_table.tax_calculation_rate_id
 LEFT JOIN `tax_calculation_rate_title` AS `title_table` ON rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = title_table.tax_calculation_rate_id AND title_table.store_id = '1' WHERE (customer_tax_class_id = 3) AND (product_tax_class_id IN ('2')) AND (rate.tax_country_id = 'US') AND (rate.tax_region_id IN(0, 12)) AND (rate.zip_is_range IS NULL) AND (rate.tax_postcode IS NULL OR rate.tax_postcode IN('*', '', '90034', '90034*', '9003*', '900*', '90*', '9*'))) UNION (SELECT `main_table`.`tax_calculation_rate_id`, `main_table`.`tax_calculation_rule_id`, `main_table`.`customer_tax_class_id`, `main_table`.`product_tax_class_id`, `rule`.`priority`, `rule`.`position`, `rule`.`calculate_subtotal`, `rate`.`rate` AS `value`, `rate`.`tax_country_id`, `rate`.`tax_region_id`, `rate`.`tax_postcode`, `rate`.`tax_calculation_rate_id`, `rate`.`code`, IF(title_table.value IS NULL, rate.code, title_table.value) AS `title` FROM `tax_calculation` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `tax_calculation_rule` AS `rule` ON `rule`.`tax_calculation_rule_id` = main_table.tax_calculation_rule_id
 INNER JOIN `tax_calculation_rate` AS `rate` ON rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = main_table.tax_calculation_rate_id
 LEFT JOIN `tax_calculation_rate_title` AS `title_table` ON rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = title_table.tax_calculation_rate_id
```

Comment: Looks like your installation didn't complete correctly.  The table `tax_calculation_rule` wasn't created.

Comment: Thanks Dougals , can you please tell how to create that table

Comment: This should be created as part of installation.  If you haven't made any updates, I would suggest reinstalling. Alternatively, install to a new database and take the schema from there and update your existing database

Comment: Have added this as an answer.

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: Magento administration issue that belongs over in magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your installation didn't complete correctly.  If you either:

a) install a fresh version if you've not undertaken any work

b) install a fresh version to a new database and copy schema for missing database tables (you'll need to run a diff between the two to capture all missing tables)